# Extract day from date string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, datetime

How can I extract only the day from a list such as this?

```
date_data = [None, None, None, None, '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-07', None, None, '2014-01-10']
```

I've tried a few different lambda functions such as:

```
Date_List = [d for y, m, d in map(lambda x: str(x).split('-'), date_data) if y != None if m != None if d != None]
```

or

```
test = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in date_data]
test1 = [datetime.strftime(i, '%d') for i in test]
```

But I cannot get the correct output which is:

```
date_data = [None, None, None, None, '05', '06', '07', None, None, '10']
```

Does someone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `[d[-2:] if d else d for d in lst]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your initial run though you could do this:

```
Date_List = [x.split('-')[2] if x else None for x in date_data]
```

which goes through the list elements and appends a none if the element is a none to begin with and if its an element then you can get the day

Answer (score 0):

Once you've used `strptime` to get a `datetime` object, you can call the `day` property to retrieve the value you're looking for. I'd encourage that over string parsing based on the location of hyphens because it's more robust to volatile input data.

```py
from datetime import datetime

dates = [None, None, None, None, '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-07', None, None, '2014-01-10']
result = []

for date in dates:
    if date is None:
        result.append(None)
    else:
        result.append(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').day)

print(result)  # [None, None, None, None, 5, 6, 7, None, None, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick list comprehension that gets the job done

`new_list = [i.split("-")[-1] if "-" in str(i) else i for i in list]`

`[None, None, None, None, '05', '06', '07', None, None, '10']`

Just loops through your original list and if there's a - in the string version of the element in splits on - and writes the last element.